# DOMPDF : spacings and margins don't match with HTML page

Tags: php, dompdf

I have this [HTML page](http://www.frakorn.it/riep.htm) and this [PDF page](http://www.frakorn.it/riep.pdf) generated by a PHP script using DOMPDF.

As you can see the margins and spacings are not the same.

Any suggestion to make a correct page?

Comment: Seems to [render ok in v0.6.0](http://eclecticgeek.com/dompdf/debug.php?identifier=f599deb9ba8c74e17444a5aaec7640d5). What version of dompdf are you using?

Answer (score 3):

This worked for me:

```
<style>
@page { margin: 0px 0px; }
</style>
```